# Git Mergetool: "No files need merging"

Tags: git, merge, cygwin, vimdiff

I am trying to configure git mergetool with vimdiff on Cygwin. I have set the the tool in my git config using:

```
git config --global merge.tool vimdiff
```

However, when I perform a merge that results in "Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result." and run:

```
git mergetool
```

I get: "No files need merging" even though git status clearly shows that I have an unmerged path.

There are several posts on SO with similar problems, but I have not been able to solve this issue with any of the solutions for the other questions. I have also removed all the lines of my .gitconfig with the except of git mergetool, and similarly, I have removed all the lines of my vimrc. Is there some other config file or some package I need (recall I am using Cygwin) to make git mergetool to open vimdiff? What am I missing? This is a trivial task on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can try with the [latest Git 2.12.1 for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (no need for Cygwin: that distribution has its own bash), to see if the issue persists.

Second, make sure the conflitcs does not comes [from files already committed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36342831/6309) with merge markers in them.

Finally, make sure to [use `git mergetool` in the right path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27192168/6309).

Comment: Indeed, using Git 2.12.1 for WIndows out of the box allows me to use `git mergetool` in Windows while in Cygwin, git mergetool returns "No files need merging". Note that I am not dealing with files already committed with merge markers and I am calling `git mergetool` from the correct path. I use Cygwin for development, so I would prefer to figure out why I cannot do the same thing with Cygwin's git.

Comment: @mjellis1687 Would the git bash be enough for your development need?

Comment: @mjellis1687 what is the version of git as deployment in Cygwin?

Comment: Cygwin has git 2.8.2-1 and 2.8.3-1. Currently, I have 2.8.3-1 although I have already tried both versions. My understanding of git bash is that it is a minimal Unix environment and does not have all the packages that Cygwin has, so I suppose one work-around is to use Cygwin and to use `git mergetool` in Git bash, but this does not seem extremely efficient.

Comment: @mjellis1687 the other approach, with Windows 10, is to use "bash on Ubuntu on Widnows": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about It has *most* of the packages you need.

Comment: @mjellis1687 If not, recompile Git in Cygwin: http://www.gizmoplex.com/wordpress/upgrade-git-to-latest-stable-release-in-cygwin/ or (more recent) https://gist.github.com/patrikbeno/92ec81e12896931b3f69

Comment: Very well. I may give recompiling Git, but for now, I will switch between environments (Cygwin and Git bash). Thanks for the link to "bash on Ubuntu on Windows".